# Unity Shader Graph Odd Tiling

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I'm trying to create a shader that tiles a texture on an object, But I am Running into an issue. When trying to tile [with this Shader Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6DH5.jpg), It looks good from the front but looks wrong from the side. [this is a 3x3x1 object and all of the squares should be the same size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXbXj.jpg) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're trying to input a Vector3 into a UV input node, which only takes a Vector2, so it's not using the Z component, which is the dimension that isn't working for you.

I haven't looked too deeply into it, but maybe this script will let you accomplish tiling in all three dimensions? https://github.com/Dsphar/Cube_Texture_Auto_Repeat_Unity/blob/master/ReCalcCubeTexture.cs